# MySql sort by ratings doesnt select those wth no ratings

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (users and ratings), one contains the users data (name, address etc), and another contains their ratings.

I want to select users and order them by their average ratings from highest to lowest, so i used this sql statement

```
SELECT user_id,AVG(rating) ave 
FROM ratings 
WHERE user_id in (SELECT user_id from users)
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY ave DESC;
```

Each user can have several ratings given by other users, while others may not have any ratings yet.

What im seeing is that sql only selects users with at least 1 rating. Those who was never rated by anybody does not get selected.

I need everyone to be listed, those with the highest ratings on top, lowest or no rating on the bottom.

Does anybody know how to fix?

Comment: Try to use a join.

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` with the `users` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a join in this kind of a query.

```
SELECT u.user_id,AVG(rating) ave 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN ratings r ON u.user_id = r.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id 
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, will try

Comment: It gives an error saying Column user_id in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Fixed it. Try again.

Comment: ok, one sec.... i will try...

Comment: it worked this time, thanks man youre a genius!!!